# Prüfer Group as a p-adic quotient

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

I've been trying to get a grasp of the structure of the p-adics to begin understanding p-adic representations. I read that the Prüfer Group $\mathbb{Z}(p^{\infty})=\underset{\underset{n}{\longrightarrow}}{\lim}\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ can be understood as the quotient $\mathbb{Q}_p/\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Could someone explain to me how this is?

My first thought is that I can understand the quotient by analogy to how $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ gives points that are "rational divisions of the circle." When considering the $p$-adic quotient above as a quotient of power series base-$p$, we seem to get what are effectively "fractions base-$p$." It seems like the coefficients $k\in\{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}$ of the negative powers $p^{-n}$ of $p$ correspond to $k^{th}$ powers of $p^{n}$'th roots of unity. My understanding here however is quite foggy.

Comment: What definition of the Prüfer group are you using?

Comment: The Prüfer group is $\bigcup_{n\ge 1} p^{-n}\Bbb{Z/Z}$ while $\Bbb{Q}_p/\Bbb{Z}_p=\bigcup_{n\ge 1} p^{-n}\Bbb{Z}_p/\Bbb{Z}_p$

Comment: @DanielHast I have added to my question the definition I'm using: the roots of unity of prime powers.

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: I think you mean $\varinjlim_n \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$, not $\varprojlim_n \mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ (the inverse limit is $\mathbb{Z}_p$, while the Prüfer group is the direct limit).

Comment: @Shaun Done, thanks.

Comment: @DanielHast Yes sorry, I have corrected this. I was just used to writing the inverse limit for the p-adic integers and mixed it up.

Comment: I gave the answer above anything unclear

Comment: @reuns I am still unclear on why those facts are true and what the intuition behind them is.

Comment: $z\to \exp(2i\pi z)$ is an isomorphism from $p^{-n}\Bbb{Z/Z}$ to the complex $p^n$-th roots of unity. It is useless to introduce the Prufer group as $\underset{\underset{n}{\longrightarrow}}{\lim}\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$.